# Landscaporientation fails

Tags: ios, ipad, uiinterfaceorientation

I am stuck with this problem for a while now and I am hoping that someone can help me with this.

This is what I've got:

An iPad App with the following screens:

1. Homescreen with 4 buttons (no Tabbar or Navigationbar) which points to several Tabs in a coded Tabbar.
2. Screen 1 Tableview
3. Screen 2 Tableview
4. Screen 3 Tableview
5. Screen 4 Sectioned TableView

My Homescreen supports Portrait as well as Landscape rotation. When I choose an option on the homescreen (which opens a new view with a tabbar), the view gets reset to PortraitView and doesn't support Landscape view anymore.

Ive added this code in all the viewcontrollers .m files:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}
```

Even a default tableview gets reset to portraitview and no longer supports landscapeview.

In my firstviewcontroller I have this code which creates the Tabbar when a Button on the homescreen has been pressed.

```
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

CategoriesOverviewController *productView = [[CategoriesOverviewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CategoriesOverviewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *TabBarItem_1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:productView];
productView.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[productView  setTitle:@"Producten"];
productView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"products.png"];

ShowcaseViewController *showcaseView = [[ShowcaseViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ShowcaseViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *TabBarItem_2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:showcaseView];
showcaseView.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[showcaseView  setTitle:@"Showcase"];
showcaseView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"showcase.png"];

EventMainmenuViewController *expoView = [[EventMainmenuViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EventMainmenuViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *TabBarItem_3 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:expoView];
expoView.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[expoView  setTitle:@"Beursagenda"];
expoView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar.png"];

CompanyViewController *companyView = [[CompanyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CompanyViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *TabBarItem_5 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:companyView];
companyView.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[companyView  setTitle:@"About"];
companyView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"About.png"];

FavoritesViewController *favoritesView = [[FavoritesViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FavoritesViewController" bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *TabBarItem_4 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:favoritesView];
favoritesView.navigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackOpaque; 
[favoritesView  setTitle:@"Favorieten"];
favoritesView.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"favorites.png"];


tabbarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: TabBarItem_1, TabBarItem_2, TabBarItem_3, TabBarItem_4, TabBarItem_5, nil];

[self presentModalViewController:tabbarController animated:YES];

tabbarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

(if there is another way of doing this, please say so!)

Whats missing here!! Do I have to send some extra information with the viewcontroller?

Plz help me!! I would appreciate it very much!!

With Kind Regards,

Douwe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the `UITabBarController` to support landscape orientation, each of its view controllers needs to support it as well.

In this case, you would need to subclass `UITabBarController` have its `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` method return `YES`, and then have each of its managed view controllers return `YES` for that orientation as well.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply PGB! Much Appreciated! All my viewcontrollers have the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method return set to YES! No difference! Do I need to put some extra information within the code for the pressedbutton (Last code piece in question Above!) thnx!

Comment: Are you returning `YES` in the `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` for each of your `UIViewControllers`? Like `CategoriesOverviewController`, `ShowcaseViewController`, `EventMainmenuViewController`, `CompanyViewController` and `FavoritesViewController`? See this Technical Q&A from Apple: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1688/_index.html